# How to know which devices are connected to my UbuntuOne account?

Tags: ubuntu-one, ubuntu-core

I istalled UbuntuCore on a RasPi 3 and it's successfully registered and accessable with SSH. my question is, is there any way to get information about this registered device from my UbuntuOne SSO account?

thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because we use macaroons, which aren't stored server-side, it is not possible to get this kind of information from the SSO account, no.

Comment: Is there any way or tool to manage the registered devices? i just want to manage three RasPis with Ubuntu core which are registered to my SSO account!

Comment: I don't understand: device registration is not stored server-side.

Comment: and that means it is unpossible to manage my connected devices! thanks for the answer.

My point of view is that i thought that ubuntuOne+UbuntuCore were design for IoT projects, but without the possibility of device managment, how could the IoT project be managed?

Comment: the device management bit is separate, and per customer (that is, per device manufacturer, more or less)